# prove $\lim_{x\to 0^-} \frac{x}{|x|} = -1$

Tags: limits, epsilon-delta

I was trying to prove this one, this is how approached it,

As its left hand side limit, For every $\epsilon $ , $\exists \delta$ such that,
if $0-\delta < x< 0$ then $|f(x) - L | < \epsilon$.

for given $\epsilon > 0$,

$|\frac{x}{|x|} + 1|<\epsilon$

my thought process somehow i have to convert this expression into "something < x" so that i can choose that "something as $\delta$"

but coming to this problem i thought as limit was approaching from left of 0, so $\frac{x}{|x|}$ will be -1 so substitute into the equation and it's just

|-1 + 1 | and its just 0, which is not the desired result,

how can i move further, any sort of hints or solution .

Comment: Why $|-1+1|=0$ is not desired?

Comment: then it just 0<$\epsilon$ ,what will be the value of $\delta$? it can't be zero

Comment: Won't $\delta=1$ work then?

Comment: Take it arbitrary $>0$, any way holds $0<\varepsilon$ - just true is what we want.

Comment: got it know, by taking any arbitrary $\delta$ it works, thank you

Comment: For $x<0$, $|x| = -x$. Hence for this domain: $\frac{x}{|x|} = \frac{x}{-x} = -1$. Any sequence $\{x_n\}_n$ in $(-\infty,0)$ converging to zero maps to the constant sequence $\{-1\}$, so the limit will be $-1$ (for this sequence). But, as constant functions are continuous, this holds arbitrarily.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Say shortly, limit definition is implication in some circumstances. When conclusion is true, then all implication is true. You have $\delta >0 \Rightarrow \varepsilon > 0$, which is tautology, so all your reasonings are correct and exactly they provide the proof.